# How to include gradle depedencies in Buildozer?

Tags: python, kivy, build.gradle, buildozer

In my buildozer.spec file I have

```
android.gradle_dependencies = com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:3.0.0
```

But when I run 'buildozer android debug' it never builds any dependencies. I've been building all my dependencies in android studio and then manually placing them in the class and res folders to get buildozer to include them for now.  But I'm having some issues with differing versions between buildozer and android studio dependencies and I'd like just do it all together.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  There's a switch between ANT and gradle at build tools 25.3.0. Further information on the topic can be found here https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/issues/1069